# Speed $v$ of a wave on a tightrope

Tags: waves, velocity, soft-question, education

Starting from D'Alembert's general wave equation we can find the propagation speed of an impulse along a tightrope as a function of linear mass density,

$$\boxed{v= \sqrt{\frac \tau \mu}} \tag 1$$

where $\tau$ it is tension of the rope (in Newton) and $\mu=m/\ell \,$ it is the mass of the rope per unit of length.

> Are there simple methods for students of an high school question who don't know calculus (derivatives and partial derivatives, of course) to be able to get the relation $(1)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know (just using trig) the formula for centripetal acceleration $v^2/r$, and (again just using trig) how to get the centripetal force as $T/r$ (analogous to the excess pressure in a soap bubble being $2T_{\rm surface}/r$) then you can see that if the rope moves  at speed $v= \sqrt{T/\mu}$ then the  curvature $\kappa=1/r$  of the rope can be anything. Now go to the frame in which the rope is stationary. In this frame  the "anything" shape will be moving  at $v= \sqrt{T/\mu}$.

Comment: In the meantime thank you very very much. Please can explain me better: 1) If you know (just using trig) the formula for centripetal acceleration: I know that $\mathbf{a}_{\text{cp}}=-v^2 \hat{\bf y}/r$. 2) Why "how to get the centripetal force as $T/r $ (analogous to the excess pressure in a soap bubble being $2T_{\text{surface}}/r$)". Who is $\kappa$? At the end of the school year my head is full and I can't connect everything. Could you so cordially explain to me step by step everything you wrote? +1 from me.

Comment: I have no time now, but $v^2/r$ is in every elementary physics book that does uniform circular motion, and the $T/r$ uses exactly the same geometry.

Comment: I didn't know there was this connection between $v^2/r$ and $T/r$. Sigh. I will wait patiently for your detailed explanation and in the meantime thank you again.

Comment: Is there a connection with this video? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GTEdQqy5Sn4

Comment: @Sebastiano. Yes that is the derivation I had in mind.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. My difficult it is to understand the English language. This it is the reason for to have further explanations with the steps. For me, having a more detailed answer with mathematical relationships makes it easier to understand.

Comment: Very nice, although I think the students will have a hard time grasping the reasoning, with the change of frame and limiting behavior of the geometric notions involved...

Answer (score 4):

You can use unit analysis to get the form of the formula.

The properties that completely define a thin string are the tension ($\tau$) with unit $N = kg\cdot{}m/s^2$ and linear mass density ($\mu$) with unit $kg/m$. From these two quantities, we need to derive a velocity. As a guess, we assume that the form of the formula is of a product of the two quantities raised to some powers:
$$v=\tau^a\mu^b$$
We can assume this because multiplication, division, and powers are the only operations that give results with different units. Addition and subtraction require the inputs to have the same units and the output will also have the same units (meters plus meters gives meters). Other operations ($\sin$, $\cos$, $\exp$, $\log$, etc.) require unitless inputs and outputs, and we don't have other quantities to cancel the units of the values we have.

By considering just the units, we can figure out what the exponents $a$ and $b$ must be.
$$\left[\frac{m}{s}\right] = \left[\frac{kg\cdot{}m}{s^2}\right]^a\left[\frac{kg}{m}\right]^b$$
The exponent $a$ must be $1/2$ to get seconds in the denominator, which means $b$ must be $-1/2$ so that we get meters in the denominator and kilograms to cancel. This results in a formula for the wave speed:
$$v = \tau^{1/2}\mu^{-1/2} = \sqrt{\frac{\tau}{\mu}}$$
The thing to watch out for is that this only gives the form of the equation. There may be unitless constants that won't show up in this kind of derivation. If you do the same derivation for the period of a pendulum ($T$) using the length of the pendulum ($L$) and the gravitational acceleration ($g$), then you will get the expression
$$T=\sqrt{\frac{L}{g}}$$
when the actual formula is
$$T=2\pi\sqrt{\frac{L}{g}}$$
The $2\pi$ is missed because it doesn't have any units. It can be derived through measurements of a real pendulum.

Comment: I give to you also the "$\infty$ thank you very much" to have had a particular attenction on my question. GRAZIE.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of a sine wave I consider a single symmetric pulse like the one in the following image. We choose a reference system in which the pulse remains stationary (i.e. we chase the pulse in so that we always have it in view). In this way the string will appear to flow in front of us from right to left with velocity $v$.

[image]

Consider a small segment of length $Δl$ of the string crossed by the impulse that forms an
arc of circle of radius $R$ and which subtends an arc of amplitude $2θ$.

[image]

It results that
$$Δl = (2θ)R \iff 2\theta=\frac{\Delta l}{R}.$$
A force of magnitude equal to the tension $\mathbf F$
acts tangentially on this segment from
both sides. The horizontal components of these two forces add up to cancel each other out, but the
vertical components add to form the
radial force.

[image]

The intensity of the resultant force $\mathbf F_{\text{radial}}$ will be

$$F_{\text{radial}}=2F\sin(\theta)\sim_0 F(2\theta)=\frac{F\Delta l}{R}$$
The mass of the segment is given by $Δ m = μ Δl \ $
where $μ$ is the linear density of the string.
We know that the string element $Δl$ is moving on an arc of a
circumference. Therefore it has a centripetal acceleration toward the center of the circle given by

$$a_{\text{cp}}=v^2/R$$
From the second law of dynamics we know that

$$\frac{F\Delta l}{R}=Δ m\frac{v^2}R= \frac{μ Δl v^2}R \tag 1$$

which solving the $(1)$ respect to the speed we get:

$$v=\sqrt{\frac{F}{\mu}}\quad .\square$$

Comment: This is a good answer. I would mark this one as accepted.

Comment: @MarkH No no. Absolutely not. I'm scarce user. With all sincerity I would like this community to change for the better and be more humble and more cooperative. I appreciate your gesture, but I am a humble person who doesn't think about votes, medals or anything else, but rather how to help others. A big hug. Thank you very much.

Comment: I understand. Although, I didn't understand the current accepted answer until I read this one. The connection to centripetal force was unclear until I saw the diagram and the frame of reference shift.

Comment: @MarkH It wasn't crystal clear to me either, but it is the highest rated answer. So I think the problem of understanding and knowledge is mine about the question. I would like so much for this community to be different and not let go of so many users who are also asking for detailed answers and true and sincere help. My besttttt regards.